# Retrieve data from Parse.com and Display it in amcharts.js or highchart.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts, parse-platform, amcharts

How can I retrieve data from Parse.com through javascript or API and display it with amcharts.js or highcharts.js?

Or are there any other chart js I can try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried using getJSON with parse.com api. And parse javascript, the codes above. 

Are there any other charts I can try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amCharts wrote a [tutorial](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/loading-external-data/) how to load external data, if you receive an array of objects you can pass it directly to the chart instance to create it or call "[validateData](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateData())" to apply the data changes.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", { ... });
...
chart.dataProvider = newDataArray;
chart.validateData();
```